# date-and-time npm module not giving correct date?

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
const datetime = require('date-and-time')

// Given the time 
const time = "Mar 10 2020 11:30:00"
```

I want to parse this into
2020-03-10T11:30:00.000Z

I tried to parse but got different value

```
const newTime = datetime.parse(time, "MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss") // returns 2020-03-10T15:30:00.000Z
```

The library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time

It messes up on the hours. Not really sure why it becomes 15:30

Comment: My solution over the years was to use https://momentjs.com/docs/ maybe you want to try using it because is simple and easy to understand. Here you have format examples https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing you the time in UTC (Zulu), which is what the Z on the end is telling you.  It looks like it is +4 hrs for your timezone.  So if your input 11:30:00 is in local time, then 15:30:00Z is correct.

If your input is in UTC, then you should add true as the third argument.  From the docs:

```
parse(dateString, arg[, utc])
```

So adjust as follows:

```
const time = "Mar 10 2020 11:30:00"
const newTime = datetime.parse(time, "MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss", true) 
// returns 2020-03-10T11:30:00.000Z"
```

Comment: you mean +4 "hrs for your time zone"?

Comment: Sure no problem :)